# Angular 4/5 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'mat-dialog-close' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular

this has happened when I tried to follow the dialog tutorial from
 https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
and I'm getting the error above so if anyone has an idea of what I should do to 
solve this problem?

here is my code :
the html for the modal

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Warning</h1>

<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Are you sure you want to delete the book {{data.title}} ?</p>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.title" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">No Thanks</button>
</div>
```

the class that active the modal:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-remove-book',
  templateUrl: './remove-book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./remove-book.component.scss']
})
export class RemoveBookComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RemoveBookComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();  
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

and the method in the class that supposes to active the modal:
  removeContact(i){ 


    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RemoveBookComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { ok: this.ok, title: this.contactsArr[i].title }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { 

      console.log('The dialog was closed');

        this.contactsArr.splice(i,1);


    });


      }
```

I did all the required imports and it should work if someone can help I would appreciate it very much.

thanks.

Comment: Have you imported the package in the module, this component belongs to?

Answer (score 36):

There are two things you need to look out for

1. make sure you import `MatDialogModule` into the module where you are using the dialog.
2. make sure that the dialog component is added to declaration in your module.

Comment: I had it only in my `entryComponents`, thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer because of 2.

Comment: + make sure the module where you're using the dialog is itself imported in the root module

Comment: Yep, #2 fixed this for me. Interesting display of error (not very helpful), but that's what I get for relying on the IDE too much (which addresses #1 automagically)

Comment: Thank you!! Everyone only kept saying the first point, nobody ever mentions the second point which is what I was missing because I copy-pasted an existing component...

Answer (score 17):

Well after I asked it on git I found my problem and it was :
to import -> MatDialogModule 
I hope it will help someone even if just giving an idea of what was wrong
check it out at:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8911

Comment: I know it's an old question...   But maybe this could help someone:  I had MatDialogModule imported, and kept gettings the same error... turned out I forgot to add my DialogContentComponent under 'Declarations' in my Module file!

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="foo(data.title)" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
```

instead of

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.title" tabindex="2">Ok</button>
```

it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well `<button mat-button mat-dialog-close="data.title" tabindex="2">Ok</button>`. I had to remove the curly brackets

Answer (score 4):

also you have to make sure that your dialog component is declared in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 2):

If your component is exported in a shared module, you need to have the angular material imports declared in the shared module too.

ex:

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { ConfirmPopupComponent } from '../confirmPopup/confirmPopup.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ConfirmPopupComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ConfirmPopupComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `[matDialogClose]` instead of `[mat-dialog-close]`.
example
`<button mat-button [matDialogClose]="data.title" cdkFocusInitial> OK </button>`.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the MatDialogModule ? For example in your app.module.ts file

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';

...

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
   ...
  ],

  imports: [
    ...
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the component in the module declarations?

If it is not standalone, this error message may be the result of it not being in *app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RemoveBookComponent,
```

Answer (score 0):

This post should be a comment because does not supplies any answer, but to be clear where we are on this issue, this is from the Angular Material documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

[image]

So your code is correct as stated in Angular Material documentation, where you can find an example but, even the directives "mat-dialog-actions" and "mat-dialog-content" do not work as intended...
And yes, the issue is yet opened at github.

Sorry for the frustration after hours of googling and SO'ing with no answer.

Comment: Hi, the error was because OP was not importing MatDialogModule. The same has been added as an answer by OP.

Comment: "mat-dialog-content" and "mat-dialog-actions" as stated on angular material documentation give a compilation error. They are not directives, but attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate option,

*Dialog HTML*

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="myMethod('result')" cdkFocusInitial>Delete</button>
```

*Dialog-Component.ts*

```
 myMethod(val){ 
    this.dialogRef.close(val);
  }
```

If you want to return result after dialog closed,

*Main-Component.ts*

```
yourMainComponentMethod(\) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDelete, {
      width: '350px',
      height: '200px',
      data: { dialogTitle: "Title", dialogText: "You will vote this!"}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      console.log(result);

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import - MatDialogModule

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

and in Button use this - [mat-dialog-close]

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" [mat-dialog-close] >Cancel</button>
```